# Set value to an aria-controls input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to set an input aria-control value. But I can't do it using the traditional jQuery way.

My code is this one:

```js
function showMessage() {
  var message = jQuery("#textToDisplay").val();
  $("#example").text(message);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="textToDisplay" />
<input type="button" value="Add message" onClick="showMessage()" />
<input aria-controls="example" type="text">
```

How can I set the value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the selector like this.your selector target the `id` not the `aria-controls` so use with [attr selector](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_attribute_equal_value.asp).Also Input not have `text()` property so change with `val()`

```js
function showMessage() {
 var message = jQuery("#textToDisplay").val();
 $("input[aria-controls=example]").val(message);
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="textToDisplay" />
<input type="button" value="Add message" onClick="showMessage()" />
<input aria-controls="example" type="text">
```

For below `Terry` comment
use `addeventlistener` instead of inline click function.That do the click function in dom like this

```js
$('#click').click(function() {
  var message = jQuery("#textToDisplay").val();
  $("input[aria-controls=example]").val(message);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="textToDisplay" />
<input type="button" id="click" value="Add message">
<input aria-controls="example" type="text">
```

Comment: Probably also good to advice that OP should use event listeners instead of inline JS bindings :)

Answer (score 2):

Use [attr selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

> Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value exactly equal to a certain value.

```
$( "input[aria-controls='example']").val(message);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$("#myId").attr("aria-controls", myValue);
```

Hope this helps!