# How to select an element of the aria-controls type?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

[aria-controls WebDriver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaPTo.jpg)

I have tried in many ways to execute the WebDriver Click() method on the button element (dropbtn):

```
//*[@id="pedigree-controls"]/div[2]/div/div/button
```

However, for some reason, maybe because it is an aria-controls and it contains a **span class="visually-hidden**", Selenium does not Click on it.

```
WebNavigator.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='pedigree-controls']/div[2]/div/div/button")).Click();
```

I was wondering if there is a way I could reach that specific element. Does anyone know how to do that?

- please, refers to the attached image.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set value to an aria-controls input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45689156/set-value-to-an-aria-controls-input)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Comment: What error do you get when you try to click on it?

Comment: JeffC, when running webdriver on C#, I get "Unable to locate element". However, when running selenium IDE, I can find the element but when I perform the click operation it says "Permission denied to access property". It is so weird!
Please, help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the answer!
The page is working with Shadow DOM Elements built with Polymer and that is why I can find the element but no action can be performed. In order to reach the citied element, I needed to find child elements in parents divs, tags, etc. until the element was reached.

Answer (score 0):

From the snapshot of the *WebElement* you have provided it seems to expand the *Dropdown* you have to invoke `click()` on the `<span>` tag with text as **Select Pedigree View:** through either of the following *Locator Strategy* :

```
WebNavigator.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='pedigree-controls']//button[@class='dropbtn']//span[@class='visually-hidden']")).Click();
//or
WebNavigator.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='pedigree-controls']//button[@class='dropbtn']//span[contains(.,'Select Pedigree View:')]")).Click();
```